# having problems inserting words on a patricia/radix tree

Tags: c, radix, recursive-datastructures, patricia-trie

i am trying to make a code for a college aplication of a patricia/radix tree that inserts words read from each line in a txt file in the tree, so if i read a file that says

```
roman
romance
romantic
```

its suposed to be implemented like

```
    (root)
      |
    roman$
   /     \
 ce$      tic$
```

ive also added checkpoints so i could test how far the program gets before dying
so my struct is set like this:

```
typedef struct no no; // declaration of the struct no

typedef struct no {
    char *str; // pointer to store a string
    struct no *child[26]; // Array of pointers to all possible children of the tree
    int isword; // Flag to know if its a full word
    int isroot; // Flag to know if its the root of the tree
} tree;
```

and my insertintree declaration:

```
no* InsertWord(no *r, char *str){
    printf("checkpoint 5 %s\n", str);
    //caso 1, we are at the root
    if(r->isroot){
        r->child[r->str[0] - 'a'] = InsertWord(r->str[r->str[0] - 'a'], str);
        return r;
    }
    //caso 2, found an empty node
    if(r->str == NULL){
        strcpy(r->str, str);
        r->isword = 1;
        printf("word %s inserted\n", str);
        return r;
    }
    //caso 3, word is a perfect fit for the prefix
    if(strcmp(r->str, str)){
        r->isword = 1;
        printf("word %s inserted\n", str);
        return r;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 0; str[i] == r->str[i]; i++);
    //caso 4, the prefix fits the first part of the word, but there is still more to be inserted
    if(i == strlen(r->str)){
        r->child[str[i] - 'a'] = InsertWord(r->child[str[i] - 'a'], str + i);
        return r;
    }
    //caso 5, the word fits the prefix, but there is still more prefix
    if(i == strlen(str)){
        char *aux1;
        char *aux2;
        strncpy(aux1, r->str, i);
        strcpy(aux2, r->str + i);
        no *aux = r;
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
            free(r->filhos[j]);
        }
        r->child[aux2[0] - 'a'] = aux;
        strcpy(r->str, aux1);
        strcpy(r->child[aux2[0] - 'a'], aux2);
        return r;
    }
    //caso 6, the first part of the word fits with the first part of the preix, but then they differ
    if(i < strlen(str) && i < strlen(r->str)){
        char *aux1;
        char *aux2;
        strncpy(aux1, r->str, i);
        strcpy(aux2, r->str + i);
        no *aux = r;
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
            free(r->child[j]);
        }
        r->child[aux2[0] - 'a'] = aux;
        strcpy(r->str, aux1);
        strcpy(r->child[aux2[0] - 'a'], aux2);
        r->child[str[i] - 'a'] = InsertWord(r->child[str[i] - 'a'], str + i);
        return r;
    }
}
```

and my current output looks something like this

```
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 3 roman
checkpoint 4 roman
checkpoint 5
checkpoint 5
```

and then the program dies, the checkpoints 1 through 4 are all related to the functions that read the file and validate the word, and they all seem to run fine

i tried adding a dynamic allocation to the program, didnt seem to help with the problem, i am aware i should provide a minimal reproduceable example but im not really sure as to where the problem lies
(the code was not originally in english i tried my best to provide a translation but if any part is still in portuguese and i didnt notice im sorry)

since it was requested of me i will add the rest of the functions that call this function, its a bit lenghty but here you go

```
no *ValidateWord(no *r, char *str) {
    int i;
    printf("checkpoint 3 %s\n", str);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] < 'A' || (str[i] > 'Z' && str[i] < 'a') || str[i] > 'z') {
            return r;
        } else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
    }
    printf("checkpoint 4 %s\n", str);
    return InsertWord(r, str);
}

no *LoadFile(no *r) {
    printf("checkpoint 1");
    printf("Insert the name of the chosen file: ");
    char namefile[100];
    scanf("%s", namefile);
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen(namefile, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("couldnt open the file.\n");
        return r;
    }
    char str[100];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp1)) {
        printf("checkpoint 2 %s\n", str);
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
        r = ValidateWord(r, str);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return r;
}
```

this is the main file that calls all of those

```
void menu(no* r) {
    int c = 0;
    printf("choose an operation:\n");
    printf("Load File - 1\nCheck Words - 2\nPrint Dictionary - 3\nLoad Stopwords File - 4\nExit - 0\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    while (c != 0) {
        if (c == 1)
            r = LoadFile(r); // Calls the LoadFile function
        else if (c == 2)
            CheckWords(r); // calls the function CheckWords
        else if (c == 3)
            PrintDictionary(r); // Calls the fucntion PrintDictionary
        else if (c == 4)
            r = LoadStopwordsFile(r); // calls the LoadStopwordsFile function
        printf("choose an operation:\n");
    printf("Load File - 1\nCheck Words - 2\nPrint Dictionary - 3\nLoad Stopwords File - 4\nExit - 0\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    }
}

int main() {
    no* r = (no*) malloc(sizeof(no)); // alocates memory for the root
    if (r == NULL) {
        printf("Error alocating memory.\n");
        return 1; // closes the aplication
    }
    r->isroot = 1; // defines the isroot flag to true
    menu(&r); // calls the menu function
    free(r); // frees the memory alocated for the root
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the driver code (the code that calls `InsertWord`) as well - it looks like maybe you're not properly initializing the child array to NULLs. --- I take it you _must_ use this specific algorithm, as opposed to trying to solve a general problem. If the latter, I might suggest a ternary tree instead.

Comment: you are right that i need to use this type of algorithm as its part of the specification for the application, i will add the rest of the code since you asked but its a bit lengthy

Comment: ok i added the rest of the code since it was requested of me

Comment: Okay, a couple of things to perhaps get you a bit further: `malloc` gives you memory but does not initialize it, so you must set all the fields explicitly - the child pointers in particular. Also with `menu(&r)`  you're passing in a pointer to the pointer `r` - I think you want just `menu(r)` there.

Comment: i did what you said but its still showing the same error, i thank you for the help regardless

Answer (score 2):

A Patrica tree is a special case of an implicit binary radix tree, which is more compact than what you have here, (to be pedantic, for sure.)

I'm not sure you need `isroot`; what is it used for? The empty tree?

`isword` is an out-of-band symbol for `$`; you do not need (or want) two symbols for the same thing. (A natural trie entry for strings which are null-terminated is to use `'\0'` as a terminal suffix `$`.)

> [Morin, Patrick. "Data Structures for Strings"](https://cglab.ca/%7Emorin/teaching/5408/notes/strings.pdf)
>
> As an optimization, edge labels can be stored in constant size by using two pointers to a string (for the first and last elements)

Instead of duplicating and manipulating the string, another option is to not copy the string, but to just point at the substring.

Edit: In the [Java code in the tutorial](https://iq.opengenus.org/radix-tree/) which you follow, it uses an out-of-band `isword` and copies the substring. It seems like you are allocating nodes, but not the copy of strings, which Java handles automatically.

I think the following is a good analog: the substring is stored in a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) at the end of the `struct`; this way, a node and a copy of the string are in a contiguous memory allocation that reduces fragmentation and calls to `malloc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

// A flexible array member for the substring.
struct node {
    struct node *child[26];
    int isword;
    char str[];
};
struct trie { struct node *root; };

// graph helper
static void graph_logic(const struct node *const node,
    const struct node *const parent, FILE *const fp) {
    fprintf(fp,
        "\tnode%p [label = \"%s\"];\n"
        "\tnode%p -> node%p [label=\"%s\"];\n",
        (const void *)node, node->isword ? "word" : "not",
        (const void *)parent, (const void *)node, node->str);
    for(struct node *const*i = node->child,
        *const*end = i + sizeof node->child / sizeof *node->child;
        i < end; i++) if(*i) graph_logic(*i, node, fp);
}
// graphs a trie in GraphViz format: https://graphviz.org/
static void graph(const struct trie *const trie, const char *const fn) {
    FILE *fp;
    assert(trie && fn);
    if(!(fp = fopen(fn, "w"))) { perror(fn); return; }
    fprintf(fp, "digraph {\n"
        "\tgraph [truecolor=true, bgcolor=transparent, fontname=modern];\n"
        "\tnode [shape=none, fontname=modern];\n"
        "\tnode%p [label=\"root\"];\n", (void *)0);
    if(trie->root) graph_logic(trie->root, 0, fp);
    fprintf(fp, "}\n");
    fclose(fp);
}

static int InsertWord(struct trie *t, char *str){
    // The tree is empty.
    if(t->root == NULL){
        struct node *r;
        const size_t len = strlen(str);
        if(!(r = malloc(sizeof t->root + len + 1))) return 0; // FAM
        *r = (struct node){0};
        r->isword = 1;
        memcpy(r->str, str, len + 1);
        t->root = r;
        printf("word %s inserted as the first word\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    assert(0); // continue this function . . .
    /* (For each edge.)
        (For each character, check that it's a match for the edge, if it's
        not, create two nodes from the split. Free the original.)
        (Or if it's the empty string, the word is already there.)
        (May be helpful to port `getFirstMismatchLetter`.) */
    return 0;
}
static int ValidateWord(struct trie *t, char *str) {
    int i;
    assert(t && str);
    printf("ValidateWord checkpoint: %s\n", str);
    // simplified
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) if(!islower(str[i])) return 0;
    return InsertWord(t, str);
}

// this inputs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree
static int test(const char *const fn) {
    FILE *fp = 0;
    int success = 1;
    if(!(fp = fopen(fn, "w"))) goto catch;
    fprintf(fp,
        "romane\n"
        "romanus\n"
        "romulus\n"
        "rubens\n"
        "ruber\n"
        "rubicon\n"
        "rubicundus\n");
    fclose(fp), fp = 0;
    if(!freopen(fn, "r", stdin)) goto catch;
    goto finally;
catch:
    success = 0;
    perror(fn);
finally:
    if(fp) fclose(fp), fp = 0;
    return success;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[100];
    struct trie t = {0};
    struct { int no; char fn[100]; } debug = { 0, { 0 } };

    // ideally, tests should be automatic
    if(!test("trie.txt")) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
        // Print a graph so we can see what's going on.
        sprintf(debug.fn, "trie%d.gv", debug.no++), graph(&t, debug.fn);
        int is_insert = ValidateWord(&t, str);
        assert(is_insert);
    }
    // memory leak: all the nodes need to be freed from the bottom.
    free(t.root);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: With one word.]

Comment: i rewrote the code without the symbol $ at the end but its still giving me the same exact error, so i dont think that is the problem here

Comment: isroot is used for the root node wich will recursevely call the same function in one of its children (the one correspodent with the first character in the string)

Comment: @DaviFranke If you tell us what your constraints are, maybe we could suggest improvements that fall within those constraints? Do you want a copy or the original? Is space a problem? Run-time?

Comment: i dont think space is a problem, my constraint is that it needs to be a radix tree as the one on this tutorial here https://iq.opengenus.org/radix-tree/ it needs to read a file and each line is a word to be added to the tree (it ignores words with numbers or symbols, and treats upper and lower case as the same) , it could either be a copy or the original
i will edit the question with my new version of the code

Comment: ok just edited the question so it has my new version of the same code
it still has the same exact issue tho

Comment: i've also marked down which error its showing and its showing this
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC000005)

Comment: I think you have to use an OOB `isword`, since Java doesn't have the null terminator. Maybe just a pointer could be good? `struct node { const char *a, *b; struct node children[26]; int isword; };`?

Comment: this code is in c not in java, im not sure what you mean by that

Comment: I've outlined a rough equivalence of the Java code that the tutorial uses and a way to see what's happening in GraphViz.